# jQuery $.post() data not being read correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, .post

I'm running into a weird bug when trying to communicate between pages using jQuery and AJAX.  I simply can't get the $.post() function to work!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form').submit(function() {  
        $.post('test.php', {'name': 'joey', 'age': 12}, function(data){
                     alert(data);
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

test.php:

```
<php?
    print_r($_POST);
?>
```

what happens when I do this is I get an alert with [object XMLDocument], but if I add 'text', as the final parameter in post, it alerts with the full php code of the file.

My problem is when i call:

```
$.post('test.php', {'name': 'joey', 'age': 12}, function(data){
                 $('#content').html(data);
       });
```

this brings up an error on firebug.  'content' is a div.  It works when I do .html('test'), but not if I do .html(data).

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
here is a dropbox folder with my entire project (like 3 files), if anyone could spend 3-4 minutes looking through it, it would help me a ton! I've been stuck here for a couple days

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ns73titud46kea7/aElaYx728G

Comment: It could be that `data` isn't valid html.

Comment: console.log your data and check if it's the expected.

Comment: Use correct php syntax :  <?php  ?>

Comment: I alert it out and it gives me the html text that's in the file.  But when i try to .html(data) nothing happens

Answer (score 2):

```
<php?
    print_r($_POST);
?>
```

should read

```
<?php
    print_r($_POST);
?>
```

I assume the php is being interpreted as an XML node, but obviously it isn't valid html

Comment: It was a typo when i typed this out, I do actually have the proper php tags. sorry for that :/

Comment: @nickelxk5 I ran your code you posted and got an error at first when I didn't have permissions set but then it worked without modifying any code. Maybe you should try again.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't matter, but try setting data's type to `'html'`

```
$.post('test.php', {'name': 'joey', 'age': 12}, function(data){
    $('#content').html(data);
}, 'html');
```

Or try using `.load()`

```
$('#content').load('test.php', {'name': 'joey', 'age': 12});
```

you might also want to try putting 12 in quotes, just to rules things out...

```
$('#content').load('test.php', {'name': 'joey', 'age': '12'});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late on the reply but could it be that you have invalid json?

```
{'name': 'joey', 'age': 12}
```

should be

```
'{"name": "joey", "age": "12"}'
```